# NUMERICAL SOLUTION OF ORDINARY DIFFERENTIAL EQUATIONS.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion, runge-kutta-methods

Here is a problem, this is in my compulsory list of homework, I'm trying to solve but it seems very hard for me, I've tried Taylor expansion, considered some cases of the value c,... Can you give me some hints to solve ?

24. Consider the problem

$Y' = \dfrac{1}{t+1}+c\cdot\tan^{-1}(Y(t))-\dfrac{1}{2},\quad Y(0)=0$

with $c$ a given constant. Since $Y'(0) = \dfrac{1}{2}$, the solution Y (t) is initially increasing as $t$ increases, regardless of the value of $c$. As best you can, show that there is a value of $c$, call it $c^∗$, for which (1) if $c > c^∗$, the solution $Y(t)$ increases indefinitely, and (2) if $c < c^∗$, then $Y(t)$ increases initially, but then peaks and decreases. Using ode45, determine $c^∗$ to within 0.00005, and then calculate the associated solution $Y(t)$ for $0 \leq t \leq 50$.

It's in problems of chapter 5 : Taylor and Runge–Kutta methods of NUMERICAL SOLUTION OF ORDINARY DIFFERENTIAL EQUATIONS, Kendall Atkinson, Weimin Han, David Stewart, University of Iowa, Iowa City, Iowa.

Here is the link of this book : [https://homepage.math.uiowa.edu/~atkinson/papers/NAODE_Book.pdf](https://homepage.math.uiowa.edu/%7Eatkinson/papers/NAODE_Book.pdf)

Many thanks.

Comment: We consider only questions that are accompanied by a certain amount of comments, attempts, etc. Otherwise, it's doing the work at your place.

Comment: Typing out the problem makes a big different, as images are not readable by people using screen readers, and also stating what the topic of the chapter is, and what tools might be someone be expected to use (i.e. what tools were introduced in the chapter?).

Comment: I have typed out everything necessary.

Comment: Use modern tools ; make a graphical representation of the field of slopes using for example Wolfram Alpha or this site https://homepages.bluffton.edu/~nesterd/apps/slopefields.html
 It will help you to make conjectures !

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it.

Comment: I can see that c^* ~ 0.549282495 but how can I prove the existence of c^* ?, can you give me some hints ?

Comment: Argue that for $c>0$ the value $y=1/2$ will be reached, and select some $c$ so that $c\arctan(1/2)>1/2$. The other case is of course $c=0$.

Comment: Can you give me more details ?, thank you so much.

Comment: It would help if you moved your obtained results from the comments to the question text, possibly with some words on the method used. (use section headers to separate the task from your solution parts.)

Comment: I have a little bit problems with the question edition, thank you so much.

Comment: The problem you quote tells you to use a numerical routine `ode45` to determine $c^*$ "to within 0.00005".  I would interpret this to mean trying various $c$ to check whether the solution is monotonically increasing.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I checked a lot of value of c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- $c=0$ can be integrated directly, $$y(t)=y_0(t)=\ln(1+t)-\frac t2,$$ and the value at $t=e^2-1>6$ is negative.
- For any $c>0$, the observed initial slope gives an initial segment where $y$ is positive.
- For $c\approx\infty$, even a small positive value of $y$ will lead to a large slope catapulting the $y$ curve towards very large values. After that the other two terms do not matter any more, the slope remains positive, $y$ does not come down, back from "almost infinity".
- One could try to make the last point a bit more quantitative by replacing "almost infinity" with some very large value, e.g., $c=1000$, and estimate the magnitude of all terms for $t=0.01$, to then find the announced behavior.

Comment: Thank you so much, Dr. Lutz Lehmann, you helped me to solve it, I have spent too much time on it.